# How to use BeautifulSoup to get text from parent and children tags to put into a DOCX table

Tags: python, css, parsing, beautifulsoup, python-docx

I am trying to use BeautifulSoup to parse the claims from google.com/patents and put them into a DOCX table.

I have managed to retrieve the claims, but unfortunately the parent div tag has the first part of the claim, and the children div-s are parts of the rest of the claim as seen in the picture below.

[image: HTML Code]

When I run the program, the first cell in the table has the parent and all the children div text in it, and the div children propagate the following table cells.

I would like to propagate the first cell in the DOCX table with the text from the Parent div while excluding the children div, and the following cells with text from the children div-s.

I have tried .decompose the claim to get the parent,
I have tried figuring out how to rename the children  to put into the table.

```
   from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
   import requests
   from docx import Document
   from docx.enum.table import WD_TABLE_DIRECTION

   document = Document()

   url = 'https://patents.google.com/patent/US7054130?oq=US7654309'

   response = requests.get(url)
   data = response.text
   soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

   claims = soup.select('div .claim-text')

   table = document.add_table(rows=1, cols=2, style='Table Grid')

   for claim in claims:

        if not claim.find('claim-ref'):

            try:
                print(claim.text + '\n')
                cells = table.add_row().cells
                cells[0].text = claim.text

                # Add space between paragraphs
                document.add_paragraph('')

            except:

                continue

    document.save('my_test.docx')
```

I want to be able to parse the claims with the text from the beginning of the claim found in the parent  into cell 1 of a DOCX table and exclude the children from the cell. The children s should go into their own cell respectively.

This is what I get when I try to run the program:
[image: This is what I get when I try to run the program]

This is what I am wanting to achieve:
[image: This is what I want]

I haven't been able to figure out how to separate the text from the parent and the children.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show what you expect your first couple of rows to look like for that URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid getting duplicates, just get the whole text from the top div and split it appropriately, for example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from docx import Document

document = Document()
url = 'https://patents.google.com/patent/US7054130?oq=US7654309'
response = requests.get(url)
data = response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
claims_section = soup.find('section', itemprop='claims').div.div
table = document.add_table(rows=0, cols=2, style='Table Grid')

for div in claims_section.find_all('div', class_='claim', recursive=False):
    div_claim_text = div.find_next('div', class_='claim-text')
    lines = [line.strip() for line in div_claim_text.text.splitlines() if line.strip()]

    for line in lines:
        cells = table.add_row().cells
        cells[0].text = line

document.save('my_test.docx')
```

This approach only stores the independent claims.

Comment: @BubbaJones, I've added an alternative approach that might help.

Comment: I thought I had the solution partially using your example with the code supplied above. Unfortunately, after trying it with other patent numbers, I find that it does not always work.

Comment: I thought I had the solution to the problem, but after tying it in real life I find that it does not work all the time. You code works great to get all the claims, but not just the Independent claims. I use the if "claim.find('claim-ref'): ... continue" section to filter the Dependent claims out. I am pretty new to Python / BeautifulSoup, so if my code looks hokey that is why. How would you correctly modify your code to just get the Independent Claims? I have tried to figure it out for a time now and looks like I have failed...

Comment: @BubbaJones, I have modified it to only return the independent claims, i.e. `1`, `16` and `29`

Answer (score 1):

You can get text from the parent `div`, then get texts from children `div`, then append data in a new list, created for this purpose.

`//div/text[1]` allows to get the first text from the div

`[e for e in _list if e]` allows to remove empty elements

Try this:

```py
from lxml import html
import requests
from docx import Document
from docx.enum.table import WD_TABLE_DIRECTION

document = Document()

url = 'https://patents.google.com/patent/US7054130?oq=US7654309'

response = requests.get(url)
data = response.text
doc = html.fromstring(data)

parent_claim = [e.strip() for e in doc.xpath("//div[@id='CLM-00001']/div[@class='claim-text']/text()[1]") if e.strip()]
children_claims = [e.strip() for e in doc.xpath("//div[@id='CLM-00001']/div[@class='claim-text']/div[@class='claim-text']/text()") if e.strip()]
table = document.add_table(rows=1, cols=2, style='Table Grid')
claims = []
for e in parent_claim:
    claims.append(e)
for e in children_claims:
    claims.append(e)

for claim in claims:

        print(claim + '\n')
        cells = table.add_row().cells
        cells[0].text = claim

        # Add space between paragraphs
        document.add_paragraph('')

document.save('my_test.docx')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, the original code retrieved all the independent claims and excluded the dependent claims. I am not sure how to implement your code to achieve the same result. I am appreciative of your effort to help. =)

Answer (score 0):

I thought I figured out the solution; but applying the code in real life has proven the code to be faulty.

The nested divs was causing duplicate entries in the table. I tried used the decompose function to fix the problem, but it fails if the claim has multiple layers of nested div tags.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from docx import Document
from docx.enum.table import WD_TABLE_DIRECTION

document = Document()
url = 'https://patents.google.com/patent/US7054130?oq=US7654309'
response = requests.get(url)
data = response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
#claims = soup.select('div .claim-text')
claims =soup.find_all("div", class_="claim-text")




for claim in claims:

    table = document.add_table(rows=0, cols=2, style='Table Grid')
    if claim.find('claim-ref'):
        continue

    else:
        try:
            claim.find('div').decompose()
        except:
            continue
        for row in claim.parent.text.split('\n'):
            if row == '':
                continue
            else:
                cells = table.add_row().cells
                cells[0].text = row
                print(row)
            # Add space between tables
    document.add_paragraph('')
```

Thanks Again!